# Как одновременно использовать установленную рядом с Windows Ubuntu для запуска на железе и в VirtualBox на Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

Хочу чтоб была возможность работать с установленной рядом с windows убунтой без ребута, возможно ли сделать это с помощью vm? Какие могут быть подводный камне, не испортит ли систему запуск с vm

Comment: Не испортит, я так делал. Главная проблема — каким-то образом пробросить диск/раздел в виртуальную машину и убедиться, что хост не будет его использовать во время работы ВМ

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box

Comment: у vmware специальные имена есть для физ. разделов, может и у VM есть, и для запуска нужны admin привилегии, чтобы к разделу был доступ. я даже одну систему таким образом угробил: сначала усыпил VM на разделе, а потом запустил на том же разделе железную загрузку